# Как сделать меню с подменю

Tags: django, menu

В html такой вид:

```
<ul> 
    <li>Главная категория
        <ul>
            <li>Подкатегория</li>
            <li>Подкатегория</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Главная категория
        <ul>
            <li>Подкатегория</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Предполагаю, что в models.py:

```
    from django.db import models


class MainCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)


    def __int__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
    maincategory = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.name
```

А вот что писать во view.py и urls.py додуматься не могу
В адресной строке должно отображаться [http://127.0.0.1:8000/Главная](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F) категория/Подкатегория/
А на странице Главная категория все Подкатегории

Answer (score 0):

Это сделать не так сложно.

Чтобы все работало как нужно, исправьте в *models.py*:

```
maincategory = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sub") # добавлен параметр related_name
```

Теперь необходимо данные получить и вывести. Файл *views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
from .models import MainCategory, Category

def menu(request):
    menu = MainCategory.objects.all()
    return render(request, "m/menu.html", {"menu": menu})

def main_category(request, main_slug):
    menu = MainCategory.objects.get(slug=main_slug)
    return HttpResponse("Category:" + menu.name)

def sub_category(request, main_slug, sub_slug):
    menu = MainCategory.objects.get(slug=main_slug)
    return HttpResponse("Category:" + menu.name + ". Sub_category:" + menu.sub.get(slug=sub_slug).name)
```

А в шаблоне это будет выглядеть вот так (templates/m/menu.html):

```
<ul> 
    {% for category in menu %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'main' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
            <ul>
            {% for sub_category in category.sub.all %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'sub' category.slug sub_category.slug%}">{{ sub_category.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Поскольку записи между собой связанны, то можно обращаться через главную модель. 
А в *urls.py* можно использовать такой способ в переменной *urlpatterns*:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("", menu),
    path("<slug:main_slug>/", main_category, name="main"),
    path("<slug:main_slug>/<slug:sub_slug>/", sub_category, name="sub")
]
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку:
    path('<slug:main_category>/', main_category),
NameError: name 'main_category' is not defined

Comment: вы функции такие создайте. в коде их нет

Comment: но если вы не можете, я могу добавить этот момент в ответ

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит, а то я кажется сильно туплю.

Comment: Изменил, пробуйте

Comment: Еще глупый вопрос чем отличается
 " from . import views " от " from .views import * "

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте это.

Comment: from . import views -- вызов функции происходит views.[название функции], а во втором случае можно просто вызвать функцию по имени, или передать ее

Comment: Само меню с подменю получилось, но внедрить его не получается, есть ли такая возможность перейти в какой либо месенджер или созвониться с тобой?

Comment: да пиши в телеграмм - @paqstd